# Почему в коде ниже, число 12 не заменяется? Неправильно составлено регулярное выражение или дело в чем-то еще?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("это 1 бакс, а это - 12.");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b1[0-2]\\b|\\b[0-9]\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while(matcher.find()){
            str.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), "rere");
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Кажется, вы хотите изменить совпадения перед заменой, да? Если это так, вы используете не тот метод. Опишите конкретный пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ищите вхождения в строке и в тоже время изменяете исходную строку - она увеличивается в размере, но размер, захваченный Matcher'ом остаётся тот, который был у первоначальной строки => метод `find()` находит всё корректно, но из-за ограничения по размеру не может захватить "2".

Comment: Пункт 1 неверный, так как 12 в строке находится между границ слова.

Comment: Согласен, поспешил.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("это 1 бакс, а это - 12.");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b1[0-2]\\b|\\b[0-9]\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        String result = matcher.replaceAll("rere");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```